# WooCommerce - Trying to add a custom field text under the product name

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I had been trying to set custom text under the product name in WooCommerce for one of the clients.

There's an Attribute that I created for each product, whose class name is "woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_underprice".

I'd like to take the value that I set in there and show it on the Product Category page (also known as Product Archive page). Additionally, it'd be great if this could ONLY work for a specific category (URL slug is /product-category/wigs).

I have pretty much never coded in JavaScript before, but from what I understand... it could look something like this?

Needless to say, when I add this code to functions.php, the whole website crashes (I must be missing a lot of things).

I appreciate any and all help!

```
function UnderPrice() {
    var id = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_underprice");
      if (id.length > 0) {
          alert (id[0].value);
      }
    }



remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

function customize_shop_page_product_title() {

    $custom_text = 'My Custom Text';
    echo '<h3 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' .UnderPrice .$custom_text.'</h3>';

}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','customize_shop_page_product_title');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are mixing JS and PHP in the same file. The code crashes because the PHP engine sees a malformed function (because it is JS) and then later you try to concatenate it into a string.
If you want to have the javascript rendered as part of your frontend template, you should put the whole function in a string variable (know though, that this is a bad practice, because it is hard to debug), or import it somehow.

Also it seems that you try to place the javascript function amid a `<h3>` tag, which would never work in the frontend. The browser will only be able to access any javascript placed between  tags, or imported from a .js file by a `<script>` tag.

The javascript function underPrice seems well-formed, syntactically. (tip: It is customary to use camelCase for functions rather than PascalCase.) Not sure what the function is supposed to do, but this would cause an popup window with some value and an ok button, if it finds the element with the two classes.

I hope this helps you forward somewhat. Since you mention little experience with JS, I would suggest to lookup some tutorials with it, there are many wonderful ones online for free, and it is well worth the time.